# angular ui calendar with require and fullCalendar is not a function error

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, ui-calendar

I am adding ui calendar from this lib https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-calendar

I have added file on my component file

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='resources/scripts/external/ui-calendar/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='resources/scripts/external/ui-calendar/fullcalendar/dist/gcal.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='resources/scripts/external/ui-calendar/fullcalendar/src/calendar.js'></script>
```

But i am facing these error on console :-

> ReferenceError: require is not defined fullcal...s?v=2.3 (line 12, col
>   3) 
>   ReferenceError: require is not defined gcal.js?v=2.3 (line 12, col
>   3)

and

> Error: scope.calendar.fullCalendar is not a function
>   update@http://localhost:8080/DigitalWare/resources/scripts/external/angular-ui/angular-ui.js?v=2.3:90:26
>   .link@http://localhost:8080/DigitalWare/resources/scripts/external/angular-ui/angular-ui.js?v=2.3:108:13

Help me to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: localhost link will not work bro

Comment: change the order of script files and add `moment.min.js` also as shown in it's document

Comment: change the order of js files

Comment: which order i need to set ?

Comment: @pro.mean I have added momentjs and changed its order  but still i am facing same issue

Comment: have you inject `['ui.calendar', 'ui.bootstrap']` in main module